# Is it possible to set a default value for a capture group in sed?

Tags: sed

I want to parse a version number like `2019.10-devel-97` or `2019.10.1` into mayor, minor and patch version.

The patch level is optional.

I came up with the following regex:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+).([0-9]+).?([0-9]+)?.*/VERSION_MACRO(\1, \2, \3)/'
```

For 2019.10.1 this correctly prints `VERSION_MACRO(2019, 10, 1)` but if there is no patch level, I will get `VERSION_MACRO(2019, 10, )`.

Is there a way to set the default value of the capture group to 0 instead of blank space?

Comment: What is expected output for `2019.10-devel-97` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct support for defaults, but you can add a statement to replace `, )` with `, 0).`

```sh
sed -E -e 's/([0-9]+).([0-9]+).?([0-9]+)?.*/VERSION_MACRO(\1, \2, \3)/' \
    -e 's/, \)/, 0)/' file
```

`sed` is a bit of a write-only language, though, Perhaps you are better off using a higher-level language for any nontrivial text processing.

```sh
awk -F . '{ OFS = ", ";
    print "VERSION_MACRO(" $1, $2, 0+$3 ")"}' file
```